# Trying to print out all of my records from MYSQL database but only 1 record is displaying

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to print out all of my records from my MYSQL database, but it is only disaplying the first record.

```
 <?php 


    class database {
        private $objDbConn;

        function __construct($db_login_info){
            $this->objDbConn = new mysqli($db_login_info['host'], $db_login_info['username'],
                                        $db_login_info['password'], $db_login_info['database']);

             if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                        die("Database connection failed". mysqli_connect_error());
                }
        }

        function getBlogPosts(){
            $objRes = mysqli_query($this->objDbConn, "SELECT * FROM blog_posts");
             if(mysqli_errno($this->objDbConn)) {
                die("Failed query: $strSql". $this->objDbConn->error);
             }
             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($objRes)) {
                return $row['title']."<br>";
             };





        }
    }

     ?>
```

The query works fine in PHPmyadmin as per below:

[image: Pic of MySQL query executing properly in PHPmyadmin]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you use `return`, it exits the function with only the string of the first row. Append the text in the while loop to a variable, and return that variable after the `while` loop.

```
$allrows="";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($objRes)) {
    $allrows.=$row['title']."<br>\n";
};
return $allrows;
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it's the right answer, mark it as answer please :)